# Transaction timeout in hibernate and Oracle

Tags: java, hibernate

Do You know how to set timeout for transaction which will be respecte by `EntityManager.persist()` opeartion? `TransactionTemplate.setTimeout()` seems to be completely ignored during inserting records. In my application it is possible that transaction tries to insert row to table which is locked by another thread. I would like to skip waiting for this lock and report it in application.

I tried to start separate thread which will interrupt transaction's thread, but interruption is ignored by oracle driver. Do You know any reliable mechanizm for transaction timeout in hibernate?

Answer (score 0):

One solution I found is to use

```
((SessionImpl) entityManager.unwrap(Session.class))
    .connection()
    .setNetworkTimeout(timeoutCleanupExceutor, (timeoutInSeconds + 1) * 1000)
```

It is not pretty, but it is only alternative which works if `TransactionTemplate.setTimeout()` was ignored.